# SSHing into a Ubuntu VM instance

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

I have an Ubuntu VM instance running on my laptop. Both Host and VM run the same OS - Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to ssh from host like

```
ssh username@<VM-IP>
```

It tries for some time and then says

```
ssh: connect to host <ip-address> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Then I tried to ping

I get `100% packet loss`. Which I guess is because there is no established route. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure ssh is installed on the VM

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Ensure networking is enabled for the guest OS

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup port-forwarding for the SSH port that the openssh-server is using in your VM. Also have a look at [Portforwarding from host to guest using port 80, but it doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/95499/40581). bodhi.zazen's answer links to the corresponding chapter in the manual, which walks through the commands needed to setup port-forwarding and uses SSH as an example. As far as I can remember you can also do this with the GUI in recent versions (since version 3 I think).